# piping to a spawn stdin

Tags: node.js, stream, streaming, pipe, gnuplot

I would like to pipe some streaming data to [feedgnuplot](https://github.com/dkogan/feedgnuplot) in order to graph it in real time

The following works:

```
// index.js
readableStream.pipe(process.stdout)

// in bash
$ node index.js | feedgnuplot --stream
```

But the following doesn't work (and this is what I want to make work):

```
// index.js
var feedgnuplot = require('child_process').spawn('feedgnuplot', ['--stream'])
readableStream.pipe(feedgnuplot.stdin)

//in bash
$ node index.js
```

I get an ECONNRESET error

EDIT: example of a readable stream as requested:

```
var util = require('util')
var Readable = require('stream').Readable

util.inherits(SomeReadableStream, Readable)

function SomeReadableStream () {
  Readable.call(this)
}

SomeReadableStream.prototype._read = function () {
  this.push(Math.random().toString()+'\n')
}

var someReadableStream = new SomeReadableStream()

someReadableStream.pipe(process.stdout)
```

Comment: Can you give us an example input file / readable stream so that we can try to replicate your issue? Also, what are your gnuplot and feedgnuplot versions?

Comment: @PaulMougel I added an example of a readable stream. I'm running gnuplot 4.6 and feedgnuplot at master

Comment: Alright… Your code example works for me (gnuplot 4.6, feedgnuplot from master, nodes v0.10.21, Mac Os 10.9), no `ECONNRESET` error. What is your OS and Node.js version?

Comment: Heh I'm an idiot I didn't test my code with as few arguments as I posted here. I screwed up in the arguments of spawn in my code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have solved your own problem you can post your own answer and accept it. This is currently the highest voted unanswered gnuplot question.

Answer (score 0):

For me, with node.js v0.10.26, your script works fine:

Script `index.js`:

```
var util = require('util')
var Readable = require('stream').Readable

util.inherits(SomeReadableStream, Readable)

function SomeReadableStream () {
  Readable.call(this)
}

SomeReadableStream.prototype._read = function () {
  this.push(Math.random().toString()+'\n')
}

var someReadableStream = new SomeReadableStream()

var feedgnuplot = require('child_process').spawn('feedgnuplot', ['--stream'])
someReadableStream.pipe(feedgnuplot.stdin)
```

And call if from a terminal as `nodejs index.js`.